# ggplot label x-axis by another column in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Here is my example:

```
df_long <- structure(list(No = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), levels = c("G", 
"C", "A", "J", "E", "D", "I", "B", "F", "H"), class = "factor"), 
    Team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("Apple", 
    "WaterM", "Banana", "Orange", "other"), class = "factor"), 
    col = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("other", 
    "Orange", "Banana", "WaterM", "Apple"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.930616, 0.844592, 0.827872, 0.704569, 0.68324, 
    0.4001, 0.003746, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.220702, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
    1e-05, 1e-05, 0.081389, 0.064499, 0.008517, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
    1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.851402, 0.798468, 0.026838, 
    1e-05, 0.00209, 1e-05, 0.001927, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.64303, 
    0.557106, 0.442654, 1e-05, 0.135806, 1e-05, 0.000522, 1e-05, 
    1e-05, 1e-05, 0.92393, 0.004512, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05), mx = c(0.930616, 
    0.930616, 0.930616, 0.930616, 0.930616, 0.4001, 0.4001, 0.4001, 
    0.4001, 0.4001, 0.220702, 0.220702, 0.220702, 0.220702, 0.220702, 
    0.081389, 0.081389, 0.081389, 0.081389, 0.081389, 1e-05, 
    1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.851402, 0.851402, 0.026838, 
    0.026838, 0.00209, 0.00209, 0.001927, 0.001927, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
    0.64303, 0.64303, 0.442654, 0.442654, 0.135806, 0.135806, 
    0.000522, 0.000522, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.92393, 0.004512, 1e-05, 
    1e-05, 1e-05), type = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), groups = structure(list(Team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), levels = c("Apple", "WaterM", "Banana", "Orange", "other"
), class = "factor"), col = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("other", 
"Orange", "Banana", "WaterM", "Apple"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    21:25, 16:20, 11:15, 6:10, 1:5, 34:35, 28:29, 30:31, 26:27, 
    32:33, 44:45, 40:41, 36:37, 38:39, 42:43, 48L, 46L, 49L, 
    50L, 47L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How do I label x-axis by most part of ratio of `Team` ? I have read so much about changing labels command, but I do not seem to get them correctly in my graph.I also tried code like below but I just don't seem to get it right.

```
cbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

label <- df_long %>% ungroup() %>% select(No, Team) %>% distinct() %>% pull(Team)

ggplot(data = df_long, mapping = aes(x = No, y = value, fill = col)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill', width = 1)+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = label) +  
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=.5))
```

[image]

Desired plot like:I want to get x-label base on highest ratio of value of `Team` deduplicate.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `facet_grid` for the effect of a grouped axis label.

```r
library(tidyverse)

cbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

ggplot(data = df_long, mapping = aes(x = No, y = value, fill = col)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill', width = 1)+ 
    scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette)+
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    facet_grid(. ~ Team, space = "free", scale = "free", switch = "x") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
          strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image]

Comment: what kind of magic is this

Answer (score 0):

Heres another option. You calculate the number in each group, then sparsely fill in the labels.

```r
library(tidyverse)


cbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

label <- df_long |>
  ungroup()|>
  group_by(No, Team)|>
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop") |>
  mutate(grp = cumsum(Team !=lag(Team, default = first(Team)))) |>
  group_by(grp) |>
  mutate(row = row_number(),
         lab = ifelse(row == ceiling(max(row/2)), as.character(Team), "")) |>
  pull(lab)

ggplot(data = df_long, mapping = aes(x = No, y = value, fill = col)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill', width = 1)+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = label)
```

[image]